# sending jquery array with ajax / json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

Hi im trying to send my arrays through ajax with json encode, but my data is always empty. What am i doing wrong. the results im trying to get with a print_r($_POST); i also tried json stringify but still not working.

js code:

```
 $("#submitboeking").click(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();


                //Cursisten
                var voornamen = [];
                var achternamen = [];
                var geslachten = [];
                var geboortedata = [];

                $("[id^='txtCursistVoornaam']").each(function() {
                    voornamen.push($(this).val());
                });
                $("[id^='txtCursistAchternaam']").each(function() {
                    achternamen.push($(this).val());
                });
                $("[id^='radCursistGeslacht']:checked").each(function() {
                    geslachten.push($(this).val());
                });
                $("[id^='txtCursistGeboortedatum']").each(function() {
                    geboortedata.push($(this).val());
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/wp-content/themes/tweb/processboeking.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:
                        {'geslachten': geslachten,
                        'voornamen': voornamen,
                        'achternamen': achternamen,
                        'geboortedata': geboortedata},
                    dataType: 'json',   

                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                     document.getElementById("overzichtboeking").innerHTML = data;

                    }
                });
```

Comment: use JSON.stringify

Comment: There's no sign of "json encode" or "json stringify" in the code you provided at all (and I wouldn't want to use JSON with PHP + jQuery: It's more trouble than it is worth).

Comment: Are you sure your four arrays are not empty?

Comment: @ControlAltDel i did but thats not working.

Comment: @AnisR.  the arrays are not empty because i console logged them beforehand in the submit and they are filled.

Comment: Can we have a look to your 'overzichtboeking.php' too?

Comment: Try adding this line in your php and check: $res = file_get_contents("php://input");
print_r($res);

Comment: @Nil it’s not a page it is a paragraph element with a id of overzichtboeking.

Comment: @nielsmartens sry, i was thinking about "processboeking.php", my bad.